# How to parameterize the LocalForward option in ssh_config?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding

I'm starting with this fully working ssh command:

```
$ ssh -fNL 3306:localhost:3306 coolio@database.example.com
```

This config gets me part of the simplification I am after:

```
Host tunnel
    HostName database.example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/coolio.example.key
    LocalForward 3306 localhost:3306
    User coolio
```

I can connect with this command, which is much better:

```
$ ssh -f -N tunnel
```

My present question is how can I parameterize it so I can do this (or similar):

```
$ ssh -f -N tunnel -p 3306
```

or:

```
$ ssh -f -N tunnel -p 5678
```

BTW, In my example up top I'm using the same port number in both places on purpose. That is what I need in this case. (But I would also like to know how to parameterize it if the ports are different.)

What I tried so far:

```
Host tunnel
    HostName database.example.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/coolio.example.key
    LocalForward %p localhost:%p
    User coolio
```

This gives the error:

> ssh/config Bad forwarding specification

Reference:
http://nerderati.com/2011/03/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not the most elegant way, but here's how I would do it:

- Replace the port specifications in your original file with a unique pattern. For example:

  ```
  LocalForward myport localhost:myport
  ```
- Alias `ssh` from within your `.bashrc`:

  ```
  alias ssh='/path/to/ssh_wrapper.pl'
  ```
- Write the file `/path/to/ssh_wrapper.pl`:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/perl

  use strict;
  use warnings;
  my $cmdline = join ' ',@ARGV;
  if($cmdline =~ / -p\s*([0-9]+)\b/ and $cmdline=~ / -N/){
       my $port = $1;
       system("sed 's/myport/$port/g' /etc/ssh/ssh_config > /tmp/ssh_config");       
  }
  else{
       system("sed 's/LocalForward/#LocalForward/' /etc/ssh/ssh_config > /tmp/ssh_config");
  }
  $cmdline .= ' -F /tmp/ssh_config';
  my $pid = fork;
  $pid ? wait : exec("/usr/bin/ssh $cmdline");
  unlink '/tmp/ssh_config';
  ```

  Basically, this will parse your `ssh` command line and if it finds a `-p` option followed by a numeric port specification, it will create a new `ssh_config` in `/tmp/ssh_config` by substituting every occurrence of `myport` with the numeric port value you specify on the command line. After that, it `fork`-`exec`s a system call to the real `ssh` with your command line. <s>If it created its own configuration file,</s> It adds a `-F` option to your command line to ensure `ssh` reads from the newly-created configuration file instead. Finally, the parent process `wait`s for the `ssh` fork to finish, after which it removes the temporary `ssh` configuration file.

**Disclaimer**

This code is untested. Try at your own risk. Back up your configuration file first!

**Edit**

The code as previously written, will break with a "Bad port specification" error when you don't supply a numeric port via `-p` so I added code to comment the `LocalForward` part out in case it's not needed. I also made sure that the substitution in the config file won't occur unless there's also a `-N` option because you might want to specify a port via `-p` without requiring forwarding (e.g. to `ssh` into a box that uses a non-standard port).

Comment: Wow! I have great respect for both you and Linux...

Comment: @MountainX See the updated answer, please.

Comment: thanks for the update. I don't know perl, but with your explanation and reading through your code, I feel comfortable with it now. And your update helps a lot, so I plan to use this solution. (It's a very interesting approach.)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way I went about this was to just make a function in my .bashrc

```
sshfw () {
    ssh -fNL "$1":localhost:"$1" "$2"
}
```

Now I can just do

```
sshfw 8890 coolio@database.example.com
```